# Using tweetsharp to pull data for a specific user

Tags: c#, tweetsharp, tweets

Using tweetsharp to pull data for a specific user: I would like to get the numbers of retweet (RT or Retweet) and the numbers of mentioning (@).

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: I'd have suggested reading the method documentation, but it all seems to be blank when you click through! http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Appendix&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

The current version of TweetSharp, version 2.0, has methods that map directly to the Twitter API.

Assuming you have the oAuth tokens for a user you can use methods like

```
.ListRetweetsOfMyTweets(...) 
.ListTweetsMentioningMe(...)
```

If you don't have access to a user's profile, you can still do a search for that user using the standard search query syntax.

```
.Search("to:JohnDoe" ... )
.Search("from:JohnDoe" ... )
```

Both should get you the details you're looking for.